# Android Emulator failed to launch, might caused by not supporting extended desktop

Tags: emulation, launch

I have been frustrated with Android Emulator for weeks after using x86 emulator. The emulator showed with blank screen for hours even if the LogCat indicate it is running, but I am afraid the application was trapped in a dead loop.

To correct this problem, I have re-installed all my computer and android developing environment, and follow every instructions I could get by searching the internet; while the result was frustrating: there was only one "system_process" running on the emulator.

Then today I noticed there is a **SystemUI error**, thus I guess if this is caused by the PC configuration when I was using **extended desktop**. So I detached my laptop from the dock and re-launched the emulator, this time it cost only about 10 seconds to get all the processes ready to simulate android phone.

So I guess there is a bug to handle PC with extended desktop enabled. If you have got similar problem when launching Android Emulator, please try detach your PC from the second display first.